# System.Assembly.Load() Error

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to load a Windows Forms application with Assembly.Load() and it's throwing this error when the bytes are trying to run:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(Boolean defaultValue)
at CrypterTestFile.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at Test.Module1.Main() in C:\Users\Jeffrey\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Test\Module1.vb:line 15
```

Here's my code:

```
Dim entryPoint As MethodInfo = Assembly.Load(IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)).EntryPoint
If entryPoint.GetParameters().Length = 0 Then
    entryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, Nothing)
Else
    entryPoint.Invoke(Nothing, New Object() {New String() {"0"}})
    'Error is being thrown ^
End If
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but it's just a simple Windows Forms application that has a label in the center of it.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to load a Winforms program that was written as a standalone EXE program.  With a Main() method that initializes Winforms.  Problem is, that was already done by your own program.  It can only be initialized once.  There's no simple fix for this, somebody has to be the boss.

Comment: Hans Passant was correct. I fixed this error by compiling the code with CodeDom and it then executed correctly. Thanks for the help.